# On the space of sequences with finitely many non-zero components with the supremum norm and its closed unit disc

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $X = \{ (x_1,x_2,\cdots): x_i \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and only finitely many } x_i\text{'s are non-zero}\}$ and $d: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a metric on $X$ defined by 
>   $$d(x,y) = \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}|x_i-y_i|$$
>   for $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,\cdots)$.
>
> $P$: $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space
>
> $Q$: The set $\{x\in X: d(\bar{0},x) \leq 1\}$ is compact where $\bar{0}$ denotes the zero element of $X$.
>
> Which of the following statements is true?
>
> a) both  $P$ and $Q$
>
> b) $P$ only
>
> c) $Q$ only
>
> d) neither $P$ nor $Q$

My attempt: I think   option a is correct  because  for in $X$ every Cauchy sequence converges and in $Q$  it is closed and bounded implies compact (Heine-Borel theorem)

Any hints/solution? Thank you

Comment: A metric space is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded. For $\mathbb R^n$, "totally bounded" is equivalent to "bounded" (hence the Heine-Borel theorem), but this is not true for all metric spaces.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik You made good suggestions for editing the question in the comments. But did you know that you can edit users' posts as well? Yes, your edit will be in the queue for approval by members with >2K reputation, but you can suggest edits on your own.

Comment: @stressedout I thought the edits would be too trivial and therefore rejected.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik  I think your suggestions were very good and I, for one, would've definitely approved your suggestions. Please do edit a post when you think you can improve it. There might be few reviewers who do not pay enough attention to the details, but I'm sure that most reviewers will see the changes and considering the fact that your suggested changes helped improve the question considerably, especially the one about the title, I'm sure they would've approved your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my thought:

Consider the sequence

$$y_n=(1, \frac{1}{2} \cdots,\frac{1}{n},0,0,0,\cdots)$$

The sequence is Cauchy in the given metric, but the limit is not in the space. To see why it's Cauchy, note that assuming $n > m$

$$d(y_n,y_m)=\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}|(y_n)_i-(y_m)_i|=\frac{1}{m+1}$$

So, given $\epsilon >0$, you can choose $m$ large enough to show that the sequence is indeed Cauchy in the given metric. However, $y_n \to (1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\cdots,\frac{1}{n},\cdots)$ which is not in the space because it has infinitely many non-zero components.

For the second one, note that a compact metric space must be complete. So, if a metric space is not complete, it can't be compact. Consider $\{y_n\}$ as constructed above.
Now $\{y_n\}$ is a sequence in $A=\{x\in X: d(0,x) \leq 1\}$ but it converges to $(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\cdots,\frac{1}{n},\cdots)$ which is again not in the space as explained. Hence, $A$ is not compact.

Answer (score 0):

One answer is already given. I am giving another approach for future.

Think $X$ as a normed linear space with   sup norm. The set $\{ e_i : i \in \mathbb{N} \},$ where $e_i$ is an element with $1$ at $i$th position and zero elsewhere, is  a  countable basis. Now by Baire category theorem  $P$ is false and $Q$ is also false as   basis is not finite ( closed unit ball is compact iff vector sapce is finite dimensional).